# The type or namespace name searchDataContext could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting

I am working with .dbml file. file name search.dbml on local computer working file but when I upload it giving me error:
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'searchDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:
Line 17:     public partial class approducts : System.Web.UI.Page

Line 18:     {

Line 19:         **searchDataContext objProduct = new searchDataContext();**

Line 20:         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Line 21:         {

Comment: obviously this class is not present in your project. i think  the .dbml file has changed after you updated it. check its designer its new name might have become searchDataContext1 or something like that.

Comment: Upload at hosting account. and I have checked name is same searchDataContext.

Comment: did you check the deisgner of your dbml file?